# ASP.NET upload your own photo and text

Tags: asp.net

I am working on doing a webapplication that can be used by clients to upload there own newsarticle, I have done the pages but I cant figure out how to make the user upload there title, text and photo?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to come up with a database structure, where tou can save the data per client.
eg. Title, Text, Picture etc...

You can save the image as binary file or save the physical location in the database..

Use [fileupload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479405.aspx) to browse the image..

Have a look at [this](http://asp.net-tutorials.com/controls/file-upload-control/) example about how to use fileupload control